# Noise playback control from terminal

Tags: music, command-line

I would like to start/stop music from a bash script. Already tried looking in noise --help, but that lists none.

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the [code of Noise/Music](https://github.com/elementary/music), there is no functionality to handle command line inputs beside of the filename as an argument.